# Why is the border only adding around the first <li> item despite all <li> items being in the <aside> element

Tags: html, css

Here is the HTML and then the CSS. As you can see the aside is covering all the li items. The CSS is using the aside tag to add the border around all of these elements, but it is only adding a border around the first li item. I have tried adding a separate aside element around each li to overcome this but this didn't work. I have inspected using chrome dev tools and couldn't understand why this is happening.

`````
<aside>[enter image description here][1]
      <h5><strong>Related posts</strong></h5>
      <ul>
        
        <li class="related-post">
          <img
            src="img/mantyping.jpg"
            alt="mantyping"
            width="100"
            height="70"
          />
          <div>
          <a href="Howtolearnwebdevelopment.html" class="related-link"
            >How to learn web development</a
          >
          <p class="related-author"><strong>By Jonas Schmed</strong></p>
        </li>
        </div>

        <li class="related-post">
          <img
            src="img/csspower.jpg"
            alt="lightning"
            width="100"
            height="70"
          />
          <div>
          <a href="Unknownpowersofcss.html" class="related-link"
            >The unknown powers of css</a
          >
          <p class="related-author"><strong>By Jim Dillon</strong></p>
        </li>
        </div>

        <li class="related-post">
          <img
            src="img/javascriptcode.png"
            alt="javascript code"
            width="100"
            height="70"
          />
          <div>
          <a href="javascriptisawesome.html" class="related-link"
            >Why Javascript is awesome</a
          >
          <p class="related-author"><strong>By Matilda</strong></p>
        </li>
      </div>

      </ul>
    </aside>



aside {
background-color: #f7f7f7;
border-top: 5px solid #1098ad;
border-bottom: 5px solid #1098ad;
padding: 50px;
width: 500px;
}````


[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/1hIls.png
`````

Comment: Your HTML syntax is all over the place - divs being closed outside the li etc. If you put your code through a validator it will highlight the problems. Put these right and you should see the borders in the correct place.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if you are looking forward to adding a border to all list items or want to add a border to the entire `aside`. In this solution, I'm showing how you can add borders to each list of items. If you want to add a border to the entire `<aside>`, just replace the `.related-post` class with `aside`. Be careful about the code formatting with correct opening and closing tags, else it may break the UI.

```css
/* aside { */
.related-post {
    background-color: #f7f7f7;
    border: 5px solid #1098ad;
    padding: 50px;
    width: 500px;
  list-style-type: none; /* It removes the bullet */
}
```

```html
<aside>
  <h5>
    <strong>Related posts</strong>
  </h5>
  <ul>
    <li class="related-post">
      <img src="https://image.shutterstock.com/image-photo/smiling-young-man-sit-table-600w-1939452445.jpg" alt="mantyping" width="100" height="70" />
      <div>
        <a href="Howtolearnwebdevelopment.html" class="related-link">How to learn web development</a>
        <p class="related-author">
          <strong>By Jonas Schmed</strong>
        </p>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li class="related-post">
      <img src="https://image.shutterstock.com/image-vector/vector-illustration-abstract-electric-lightning-600w-1706216764.jpg" alt="lightning" width="100" height="70" />
      <div>
        <a href="Unknownpowersofcss.html" class="related-link">The unknown powers of css</a>
        <p class="related-author">
          <strong>By Jim Dillon</strong>
        </p>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li class="related-post">
      <img src="https://image.shutterstock.com/image-photo/digital-technology-software-development-concept-600w-2111828198.jpg" alt="javascript code" width="100" height="70" />
      <div>
        <a href="javascriptisawesome.html" class="related-link">Why Javascript is awesome</a>
        <p class="related-author">
          <strong>By Matilda</strong>
        </p>
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</aside>
```

Hope it helps.